# Where should I put input file in docker environment?

Tags: bash, docker, latex, docker-image, wsl-2

I am a newbie in `Docker`. I introduced the `Docker` environment in `WSL2` (`Windows10Home`). I do not wish to use the `VSCode` for simpler implementation. I would like to rather use the `Ubuntu` terminal. When I try to compile my `LaTeX` file (`my_input.tex`) with a `Docker` image (https://hub.docker.com/r/weichuntsai/texlive-small), but it complains that there is no such a `tex` file.

`docker run --name mylatex -dt -v /home/myname:/home weichuntsai/texlive-small:1.1.0`

When I send the following command in the terminal, he complains of no corresponding file.

`txrun my_input.tex xelex`, although I created this `tex` file in the home
(`~`, or `home/myname`) directory.

Sending `ls` returns `tex.mf` only without showing `my_input.tex` unfortunately.
Sending `pwd` returns `root` with some reasons. I have no idea why it returns `root`, not `home/myname`.

It may be due to my insufficient understanding of `Docker`, but I appreciate your kind advice on
that question.

N.B. I became to know that `Docker images` are located in `/var/lib/docker`.
To change this directory, one must stop the `Docker` daemon with
`sudo service docker stop`. Then one must edit `/etc/docker/daemon.json`.

```
{
 "data-root": "/to/some/path"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Checking Dockerfile of your image shows that working directory is root https://hub.docker.com/r/weichuntsai/texlive-small/dockerfile

Just mount your home to container root:

```
docker run --name mylatex -dt -v /home/myname:/root weichuntsai/texlive-small:1.1.0
```

**OR** inside container change to home by `cd /home`

Comment: thanks. The upper statement does not work. My home must be always a container home? The latter statement is OK, but it is too complicated for me.  The compilation command then becomes `txrun ../home/my_input.tex xelatex`. After the pdf generation, one must move it to my bash home. I always refer to the tree relation between the container and the bash.

Answer (score 0):

Checking Dockerfile of your image shows that working directory is root https://hub.docker.com/r/weichuntsai/texlive-small/dockerfile

Just mount your home to container root:

```
docker run --name mylatex -dt -v "/home/me":"/file" weichuntsai/texlive-small:1.1.0
```

OR inside container change to home by cd /home

and then you access your file like

```
docker exec -it mylatex bash
cd /file
ls
```